# WinScp SFTP upload is deadly slow

Tags: sftp, winscp

Recently we updated our WinScp from **5.1.3** to **5.7.3**, the problem is our SFTP upload speed is very low compared to the older version (new: 250KB/s vs old: 2.7MB/s), but normal FTP is not affected, we create sessions with default parameters in both versions, unfortunately I couldn't found any documentation regarding to this problem on the official website.

Is there any configuration that we are missing here which cause this huge difference?

**UPDATE**

Log from 5.7.3

```
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.665 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 WinSCP Version 5.7.3 (Build 5438) (OS 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 - Windows 7 Professional)
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Log level: Normal, Logging passwords
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Local account: Lenoardo\Hesenpai
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Working directory: C:\Users\Hesenpai\Downloads\WinScp\winscp573
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Process ID: 78112
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Command-line: "C:\Users\Hesenpai\Downloads\WinScp\winscp573\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Time zone: Current: GMT+4:30, Standard: GMT+3:30 (Iran Standard Time), DST: GMT+4:30 (Iran Daylight Time), DST Start: 3/21/2015, DST End: 9/21/2015
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Login time: Saturday, June 06, 2015 7:04:36 PM
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Session name: admin@192.168.1.104 (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Host name: 192.168.1.104 (Port: 22)
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 User name: admin (Password: admin, Key file: No)
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Tunnel: No
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Transfer Protocol: SFTP (SCP)
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Ping type: -, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Disable Nagle: No
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Proxy: none
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Send buffer: 262144
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Bypass authentication: No
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.666 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: No
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 Ciphers: aes,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 KEX: dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,dh-group1-sha1,rsa,WARN
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 SSH Bugs: A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 Simple channel: Yes
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: A
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 Shell: default
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 EOL: 0, UTF: 2
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 SFTP Bugs: A,A
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 SFTP Server: default
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 DST mode: 1
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.667 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.767 Looking up host "192.168.1.104"
. 2015-06-06 19:04:36.767 Connecting to 192.168.1.104 port 22
. 2015-06-06 19:04:41.781 Server version: SSH-2.0-CoreFTP-0.3.3
. 2015-06-06 19:04:41.781 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2015-06-06 19:04:41.781 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.7.3
. 2015-06-06 19:04:41.784 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
. 2015-06-06 19:04:41.808 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.605 Verifying host key rsa2 0x10001,0xc8ddef427f870847 3a75b5dbe94a2f83 c987e09c60e16208 0861960220c9071f c746728db9fdf1d2 f6893bfe61baa849 a395b0663303a72c 6460d21a168d8405 af092136521bb718 2f74d8d550fb2837 4ae7f72924c7767f c48c9a81fe4a210a ab5e926e76e45728 49b509825d899bad 24a1813e301c4438 de4fceca8f457769  with fingerprint ssh-rsa 1024 0d:5f:93:b3:48:9f:5c:60:a3:31:29:c3:38:5f:20:57
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.631 Host key matches cached key
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.631 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.631 ssh-rsa 1024 0d:5f:93:b3:48:9f:5c:60:a3:31:29:c3:38:5f:20:57
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.631 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.631 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.635 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.635 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
! 2015-06-06 19:04:42.639 Using username "admin".
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.696 Prompt (password, "SSH password", <no instructions>, "&Password: ")
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.696 Using stored password.
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.749 Sent password
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.758 Access granted
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.758 Opening session as main channel
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.762 Opened main channel
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.784 Started a shell/command
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.802 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.802 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2015-06-06 19:04:42.803 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2015-06-06 19:04:42.857 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2015-06-06 19:04:43.065 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 5, Number: -1
. 2015-06-06 19:04:43.065 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2015-06-06 19:04:43.065 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2015-06-06 19:04:43.065 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 string are not mandatory
. 2015-06-06 19:04:43.065 Getting current directory name.
. 2015-06-06 19:04:43.066 Getting real path for '.'
> 2015-06-06 19:04:43.066 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 10, Number: 16
< 2015-06-06 19:04:43.069 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 23, Number: 16
. 2015-06-06 19:04:43.069 Real path is '/'
. 2015-06-06 19:04:43.262 Listing directory "/".
> 2015-06-06 19:04:43.262 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 10, Number: 267
< 2015-06-06 19:04:43.270 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 22, Number: 267
> 2015-06-06 19:04:43.270 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 22, Number: 524
< 2015-06-06 19:04:43.274 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 114, Number: 524
> 2015-06-06 19:04:43.274 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 22, Number: 780
< 2015-06-06 19:04:43.278 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 780
< 2015-06-06 19:04:43.278 Status code: 1
> 2015-06-06 19:04:43.278 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 22, Number: 1028
. 2015-06-06 19:04:43.278 files;D;0;2015-06-06T14:31:46.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2015-06-06 19:04:43.362 Startup conversation with host finished.
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.606 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/"
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.607   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: Yes; Mask: *.*
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.607   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.607   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.607 File: 'C:\test.report' [2015-03-17T01:14:34.000Z] [7950478]
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.607 Copying "C:\test.report" to remote directory started.
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.608 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.608 Checking existence of file.
> 2015-06-06 19:05:31.608 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 21, Number: 1287
< 2015-06-06 19:05:31.608 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 1028
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.608 Discarding reserved response
< 2015-06-06 19:05:31.617 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 29, Number: 1287
< 2015-06-06 19:05:31.617 Status code: 2
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.617 Checking existence of partially transfered file.
> 2015-06-06 19:05:31.617 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 30, Number: 1543
< 2015-06-06 19:05:31.621 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 29, Number: 1543
< 2015-06-06 19:05:31.621 Status code: 2
. 2015-06-06 19:05:31.621 Opening remote file.
> 2015-06-06 19:05:31.621 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 46, Number: 1795
< 2015-06-06 19:05:31.630 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 23, Number: 1795
> 2015-06-06 19:05:31.631 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 4131, Number: 2310
. 2015-06-06 19:06:56.918 501 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2015-06-06 19:06:56.918 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 23, Number: 67076
< 2015-06-06 19:06:56.918 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 66054
< 2015-06-06 19:06:57.659 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 66310
< 2015-06-06 19:06:58.851 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 66566
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.357 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 66822
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.561 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 67076
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.561 Status code: 0
> 2015-06-06 19:07:00.561 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 46, Number: 67346
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.567 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 67346
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.567 Status code: 0
. 2015-06-06 19:07:00.567 Preserving timestamp [2015-03-17T01:14:34.000Z]
> 2015-06-06 19:07:00.567 Type: SSH_FXP_SETSTAT, Size: 33, Number: 2057
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.571 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 2057
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.571 Status code: 0
. 2015-06-06 19:07:00.571 Transfer done: 'C:\test.report' [7950478]
. 2015-06-06 19:07:00.572 Listing directory "/".
> 2015-06-06 19:07:00.572 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 10, Number: 67595
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.577 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 22, Number: 67595
> 2015-06-06 19:07:00.577 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 22, Number: 67852
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.581 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 231, Number: 67852
> 2015-06-06 19:07:00.582 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 22, Number: 68108
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.586 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 68108
< 2015-06-06 19:07:00.586 Status code: 1
> 2015-06-06 19:07:00.586 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 22, Number: 68356
. 2015-06-06 19:07:00.586 files;D;0;2015-06-06T14:31:46.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2015-06-06 19:07:00.586 test.report;-;7950478;2015-03-17T01:14:34.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2015-06-06 19:07:06.345 Closing connection.
. 2015-06-06 19:07:06.345 Sending special code: 12
. 2015-06-06 19:07:06.345 Sent EOF message
```

Log from 5.1.3

```
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.474 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.474 WinSCP Version 5.1.3 (Build 2881) (OS 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1)
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.474 Configuration: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Local account: Lenoardo\Hesenpai
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Working directory: C:\Users\Hesenpai\Downloads\WinScp\winscp513
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Command-line: "C:\Users\Hesenpai\Downloads\WinScp\winscp513\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Time zone: Current: GMT+4:30, Standard: GMT+3:30, DST: GMT+4:30, DST Start: 3/21/2015, DST End: 9/21/2015
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Login time: Saturday, June 06, 2015 6:56:01 PM
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Session name: admin@192.168.1.104 (Modified stored session)
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Host name: 192.168.1.104 (Port: 22)
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 User name: admin (Password: Yes, Key file: No)
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Tunnel: No
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Transfer Protocol: SFTP (SCP)
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Ping type: -, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.475 Proxy: none
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 Bypass authentication: No
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: No
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 Ciphers: aes,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 SSH Bugs: A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 SFTP Bugs: A,A
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: A
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 Shell: default
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 EOL: 0, UTF: 2
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 DST mode: 1
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.476 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.577 Looking up host "192.168.1.104"
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.577 Connecting to 192.168.1.104 port 22
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.629 Server version: SSH-2.0-CoreFTP-0.3.3
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.629 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.629 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.1.3
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.634 Using Diffie-Hellman with standard group "group14"
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.634 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.886 Verifying host key rsa2 0x10001,0xc8ddef427f8708473a75b5dbe94a2f83c987e09c60e162080861960220c9071fc746728db9fdf1d2f6893bfe61baa849a395b0663303a72c6460d21a168d8405af092136521bb7182f74d8d550fb28374ae7f72924c7767fc48c9a81fe4a210aab5e926e76e4572849b509825d899bad24a1813e301c4438de4fceca8f457769 with fingerprint ssh-rsa 1024 0d:5f:93:b3:48:9f:5c:60:a3:31:29:c3:38:5f:20:57
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.939 Host key matches cached key
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.939 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.939 ssh-rsa 1024 0d:5f:93:b3:48:9f:5c:60:a3:31:29:c3:38:5f:20:57
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.939 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.939 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.943 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2015-06-06 18:56:01.943 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
! 2015-06-06 18:56:01.948 Using username "admin".
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.001 Prompt (7, SSH password, , &Password: )
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.001 Using stored password.
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.058 Sent password
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.062 Access granted
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.067 Opened channel for session
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.202 Started a shell/command
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.211 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.211 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.212 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2015-06-06 18:56:02.266 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2015-06-06 18:56:02.482 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 5, Number: -1
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.482 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.482 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.482 We will use UTF-8 strings for status messages only
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.519 Getting current directory name.
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.519 Getting real path for '.'
> 2015-06-06 18:56:02.519 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 10, Number: 16
< 2015-06-06 18:56:02.524 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 23, Number: 16
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.524 Real path is '/'
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.669 Listing directory "/".
> 2015-06-06 18:56:02.669 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 10, Number: 267
< 2015-06-06 18:56:02.678 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 22, Number: 267
> 2015-06-06 18:56:02.678 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 22, Number: 524
< 2015-06-06 18:56:02.686 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 2773, Number: 524
> 2015-06-06 18:56:02.686 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 22, Number: 780
< 2015-06-06 18:56:02.769 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 780
< 2015-06-06 18:56:02.769 Status code: 1
> 2015-06-06 18:56:02.769 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 22, Number: 1028
. 2015-06-06 18:56:02.869 Startup conversation with host finished.
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.791 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/"
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.791   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: Yes; Mask: *.*
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.791   TM: B; ClAr: No; CPS: 0; InclM: 
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.791   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.791 File: "C:\test.report"
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.792 Copying "C:\test.report" to remote directory started.
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.792 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.793 Checking existence of file.
> 2015-06-06 18:56:08.793 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 21, Number: 1287
< 2015-06-06 18:56:08.793 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 1028
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.793 Discarding reserved response
< 2015-06-06 18:56:08.803 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 29, Number: 1287
< 2015-06-06 18:56:08.803 Status code: 2
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.803 Checking existence of partially transfered file.
> 2015-06-06 18:56:08.803 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 30, Number: 1543
< 2015-06-06 18:56:08.806 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 29, Number: 1543
< 2015-06-06 18:56:08.806 Status code: 2
. 2015-06-06 18:56:08.806 Opening remote file.
> 2015-06-06 18:56:08.806 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 46, Number: 1795
< 2015-06-06 18:56:08.809 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 23, Number: 1795
> 2015-06-06 18:56:08.809 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 4131, Number: 2310
. 2015-06-06 18:56:19.751 506 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2015-06-06 18:56:19.751 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 23, Number: 67588
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.751 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 66822
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.751 Status code: 0
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.759 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 67078
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.762 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 67334
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.978 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 67588
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.978 Status code: 0
> 2015-06-06 18:56:19.978 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 46, Number: 67858
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.982 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 67858
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.983 Status code: 0
> 2015-06-06 18:56:19.983 Type: SSH_FXP_SETSTAT, Size: 33, Number: 2057
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.986 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 2057
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.986 Status code: 0
. 2015-06-06 18:56:19.987 Listing directory "/".
> 2015-06-06 18:56:19.987 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 10, Number: 68107
< 2015-06-06 18:56:19.990 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 22, Number: 68107
> 2015-06-06 18:56:19.991 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 22, Number: 68364
< 2015-06-06 18:56:20.001 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 2890, Number: 68364
> 2015-06-06 18:56:20.001 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 22, Number: 68620
< 2015-06-06 18:56:20.006 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 68620
< 2015-06-06 18:56:20.006 Status code: 1
> 2015-06-06 18:56:20.007 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 22, Number: 68868
. 2015-06-06 18:56:25.033 Closing connection.
. 2015-06-06 18:56:25.033 Sending special code: 12
. 2015-06-06 18:56:25.033 Sent EOF message
```

**UPDATE 2**

it seems the problem is present from version 5.2.5 and above, however I noticed during my tests that it only occured with CoreFTP server for me, I tested it with Solarwind FTP server and everything worked smoothly, actually the newer versions were faster with the latter. then I tested with Psftp 0.64 client and CoreFTP but it didn't had the problem.

Comment: Is the upload CPU-bound (i.e. 1 core running at 100% all the time)?

Comment: no, my cpu usage is minimal on both versions (under 10% on all cores)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ,updated the question with logs, just one thing I didn't have access to the work machine, so I tested it on my  own computer, the difference on my test wasn't that huge (about 2.5X slower in newer version compared to 10X at work) but still the problem happened.

Comment: Thanks. Can you try to find out [what version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winscp/files/WinSCP/) introduced the difference? (Start with trying 5.5.6 and 5.1.8). Once you do, please post log file on [Debug-1 level](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_logging).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I tested the versions as you said and got the logs and updated the question accordingly, but the logs are huge and I can't post them here, do you want me to open a bug report in the WinSCP forum with the same title and information including the logs?

Comment: It would be definitely better to move this to the WinSCP forum. Post a link here once you do.

Comment: What version of psftp did you test this with?

Comment: A problem starting with 5.2.5 would indicate CPU-bound problem (contrary to your findings), as this version introduced SHA-256 KEX and MAC.

Comment: heh. Don't forget to come back and post an answer here once its solved?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl here is the link in the forum http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=57247#57247

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I doubled check my CPU usage and its very low, and as I said it only happened with CoreFTP server, I used Psftp 0.64 for comparison and it was OK, thanks for your support